# Why I can't import upper level modules or functions?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have such a project structure:

```
scripts:
   apps:
      __init__.py
      app.py
   baike:
      __init__.py
      search.py

    __init__.py
```

I PyCharm, I marked 'scripts' as project source root, and in apps/app.py, I want to import:

```
from scripts.baike import Query
```

In baike.py, I have:

```
class Query(object):
     def __init__(self):
        pass

     def query(text):
        pass
```

What I want is to import the 'query' function from baike.Query class. However, when I type 'scripts.' in PyCharm, 'scripts' is not available for import. I didn't create any setup.py, and just want to use the 'scripts' as the source root.

What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to import modules that come from upper level dirs is to mark the dir `scripts` as Root.
To do that in PyCharm, right click on the folder `scripts` and click on `Mark Directory as` > `Sources Root`. It should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, I did that. But then in app.py when I type 'from scripts ', 'scripts' is still not available for importing.

Comment: Do we agree that, if you have set `scripts` as Root Directory, you can directly do `from baike import Query` ? As `scripts` is root, it is what is inside that can be called like that. does it make sense?

Comment: You are right. Sorry! I was still trying to import from scripts.baike.